# How to capture variable string in replace()?

Tags: javascript

Code like this:

```
var v = 'd';
var re =  new RegExp('a(.*?)' + v, 'gi');
"abcd".replace(re,re.$1);
```

I want to get "bc".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Switching_words_in_a_string

Comment: `var res = "abcd".replace(re,'$1');
console.log(res);` will to do what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simply `$1` in a string to get the result of the first capturing group:

```js
var re = /a(.*)d/gi
var output = "abcd".replace(re,"$1")

console.log(output) //"bc"
```

Comment: @fbi020 You can mark an answer as 'accepted' by the checkmark, to help others find better answers. If you do so, you will get 2 rep as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with:

```js
let str = "abcd";
let bc = str.replace(/a(.*)d/g,"$1"); 
console.log(bc) //bc
```

The "`$1`" captures whatever is in the regex `()` bracket.